# Receiving error[E0276]: impl has stricter requirements than trait with generics

Tags: rust

I'm trying to define a trait to compare two given parameters and return a `Result` based on the implementation. It has two generics but they can be anything when we implement it:

```
pub trait Assert<L: Any + Debug> {
    fn compare<R: Any + Debug>(self, target: R) -> AssertResult;
}
```

Now, when I want to implement equal, I will do:

```
pub struct Equal<L> {
    expected: L,
}

impl<L> Equal<L> {
    pub fn new(expected: L) -> Equal<L> {
        Equal { expected: expected }
    }
}

impl<L: 'static + fmt::Debug> Assert<L> for Equal<L> {
    fn compare<R: PartialEq<L> + fmt::Debug>(self, target: R) -> AssertResult {
        if target == self.expected {
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(format!(
                "Expected {:?}, received {:?}",
                self.expected,
                target
            ))
        }
    }
}
```

Link to [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=353a5d38a729b6ed3618c3e8833101ce&version=stable).

I want to be able to accept anything as `L` and `R` but restrict them in the implementation. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach though.

Comment: The parameter L for the trait doesn't seem to many any sense since you never mention it anywhere else within the trait.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve. Can you try to explain it a little more?

Comment: @sellibitze `L` is the `expected` part, in the struct.

Comment: Yeah, but the `L` in the trait definition is literally useless.

Comment: @sellibitze oh I see. I removed that L from the trait: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=da04cadd57444d377d5defca1da333bd&version=stable

Does it make clearer for you?

Comment: The problem is that in your implementation of the trait you have more constraints for R than in the definition of the trait. That's what the error message says. The trait promises that any implementer is able to deal with any type R that is Any and Debug. But in the implementation you additionally require PartialEq. So, your implemented compare doesn't work for any Any/Debug type but only those that implement PartialEq.

Comment: @sellibitze hmm, I made a change and now I can compile it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e817a2b29feb612197c3dfc8e51eea1d&version=stable -- all I did was moving the generics to the trait and not I can make it stricter. I don't know what is the difference though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `L` in `Assert<L>` is unused by the trait, so it serves no purpose; I'm going to ignore it. Without that complication, here's what you wrote:

```
pub trait Assert {
    fn compare<R: Any + Debug>(self, target: R) -> AssertResult;
}
```

This is a contract that says, "When a type implements `Assert`, it shall provide a method `compare` that can be called with an argument of any type implementing `Any` and `Debug`."

```
impl<L: 'static + fmt::Debug> Assert for Equal<L> {
```

This is an agreement to implement the `Assert` contract for `Equal<L>` where `L` is any type that is `'static` and implements `Debug`.

```
    fn compare<R: PartialEq<L> + fmt::Debug>(self, target: R) -> AssertResult {
```

This a violation of the `Assert` contract, which said: "shall provide a method `compare` that can be called with an argument of any type implementing `Any` and `Debug`." The `compare` method you provided does not satisfy those conditions, but can only be called with an argument of a type that implements `PartialEq<L>` and `Debug`.

Or, more concisely: You signed a contract that said `compare<R: Any + Debug>` and tried to deliver a product that was actually `compare<R: PartialEq<L> + fmt::Debug>`, and the compiler got mad, because you weren't upholding your end of the contract.

---

#### How to fix it?

One possible correction (that you are already aware of) looks like this:

```
pub trait Assert<R> {
    fn compare(self, target: R) -> AssertResult;
}
```

A contract that says, "A type that implements `Assert<R>` (where `R` is any type) shall provide a method `compare` that can be called with an argument of type `R`."

```
impl<L: fmt::Debug, R: PartialEq<L> + fmt::Debug> Assert<R> for Equal<L> {
```

An agreement to implement `Assert<R>` for `Equal<L>` as long as `L` implements `Debug` and `R` implements `PartialEq<L>` and `Debug`.

```
    fn compare(self, target: R) -> AssertResult {
```

The fulfillment of the `Assert` contract: a method `compare` that can be called on an argument of type `R`. The body of this method may depend on the knowledge that `R: PartialEq<L>`, since that's in the terms of its "contract".

The combination of the `trait` and the `impl` establish the terms of the contract that the `impl` must fulfill. The first thing you wrote establishes a particular set of terms, and then attempts to deliver a product (the `compare` method) that doesn't satisfy those terms. The fix outlined above modifies the terms to include all the conditions needed to write the `compare` method.